# Limiting Spring OAuth2 authentication to registered users of application

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I was able to get the following sample code to work: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/.  It works very well, however, it allows **anyone** with a Github credentials the ability to access my application!

What I'd like to do is extend the sample code's functionality to basically validate that the authenticated Oauth2 principal is also a previously registered user of the application.  If they are not registered, they will be redirected to a registration screen.

I was thinking of utilizing a AuthenticationSuccessHandler to handle the registered user validation and perhaps invalidate their Github security token (somehow) if they are not a registered user.  Am I going down the wrong path?

Comment: You should use Github (or any other authentication provider as Facebook, Google, etc.) for authentication and if you want to consume user's resources hold by those providers. So if you don't want every Github user to access your application and you ain't going to consume any resource in there then maybe you should consider creating your own [authorization server](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver).

Comment: Figured it out.  Created a new filter class that extended AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and added it to my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's configure method.